# What is the quickest way to send a word at cursor to use as arugment with :command?

Tags: vim

Let say I want to run grep on the word at cursor position. I would do `yiw` and then use `ctrl-r "` in command window (after `:grep`).

What is the quicker way to send a word to command window with less keystroke?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
<C-r><C-w>
```

From `:help cmdine-editing`:

```
CTRL-R CTRL-F
CTRL-R CTRL-P
CTRL-R CTRL-W
CTRL-R CTRL-A
                Insert the object under the cursor:
                        CTRL-F  the Filename under the cursor
                        CTRL-P  the Filename under the cursor, expanded with
                                'path' as in |gf|
                        CTRL-W  the Word under the cursor
                        CTRL-A  the WORD under the cursor; see |WORD|
```